# Core Data NSPredicate with to-Many Relationship

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have two Entities in CoreData called User and Coupon, they are in Many-to-Many relationship. I wanted to fetch for all Coupons except those owned by user.userId = 1, where userId is NSString.

I used: 
`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT(ANY couponOwners.userId = %@)", @"4"];`
to be the predicate of my fetchedResultsController

but not filtering with correct results. One of the User in couponOwners of the Coupon is still having userId = 4.

Could somebody please help? I have been stuck for quite a while. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Core Data predicates with "NOT ANY" do not work (that seem to be a Core Data bug). Actually

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT(ANY couponOwners.userId = %@)", @"4"];
```

returns the same result set as

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY couponOwners.userId != %@", @"4"];
```

which is of course wrong. As a workaround, you can use a SUBQUERY:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(couponOwners, $c, $c.userId == %@).@count == 0", @"4"]
```

Comment: @Martin R, I have a problem with forming a correct predicate, as I see you are understand this field very well, could you please help with this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464898/how-to-form-predicate-to-get-objects-from-core-data-that-contain-string-elements?noredirect=1#comment62431649_37464898?