# Predicate Only Returns One Object

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I am using Core Data for a strategy game. A player of this game has several Characters, which can be assigned to Armies. A Character has a many to many relationship with the armies to which it belongs, the inverse of which is the Characters many to many relationship of Army.

I would like to prevent the player from assigning a character to the same army repeatedly. To that end, when formulating a fetch request in a view controller to allow the player to select Characters to assign to the current Army, I would like to filter out all the Characters who are already in the army. What I have now is below.

```
    NSFetchRequest* allCharacters = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [allCharacters setEntity: [NSEntityDescription entityForName: @"Character" inManagedObjectContext: _managedObjectContext]];
    allCharacters.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"name" ascending: YES]];
    [allCharacters setPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"0 != SUBQUERY(armies, $element, $element.name like %@)", currArmy.name]];
    _fetchedObjectController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest: allCharacters managedObjectContext: _managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath: nil cacheName: @"Armies"];
    NSError* error;
    [_fetchedObjectController performFetch: &error];
```

This code, however, only returns one Character who meets the criteria. My attempts to google the problem, or even to find some authoritative documentation about this command that might be helpful have failed. What am I doing wrong -- or is there a better way altogether to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `LIKE` in a predicate does a simple wildcard matching (with `?` and `*`
  as wildcard characters). You probably want to compare with a simple `==`.
- `SUBQUERY()` returns a collection of objects and is usually used together with `@count`
  in a predicate.
- Instead of comparing `$element.name` with `currArmy.name`, you can compare `$element`
  with `currArmy` directly.

The following predicate should work to find all objects that are *not* related to the
current army:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SUBQUERY(armies, $element, $element == %@).@count == 0", currArmy]
```

(The SUBQUERY is only needed because `NOT ANY` does not work correctly in a Core Data
predicate, compare [Core Data NSPredicate with to-Many Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722930/core-data-nspredicate-with-to-many-relationship).)