# CoreData: NSPredicate with to-many relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

Please help me make right fetch request.
I want to fetch all Requests where rates.identRater!='someIdent'
I try with predicates:

## 1

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"!(ANY rates.identRater == %@)", identRater]
```

## 2

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NONE rates.identRater == %@", identRater]
```

## 3

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"!(%@ IN rates.identRater)", identRater]
```

## Requests properties

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * additionalInfo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * duplicate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * dateAccept;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * dateCreate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * dateChanged;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * dateOfSale;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * fio;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * ident;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * identChanger;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * identOwner;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * identSelectedRate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * phone;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * status;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Rates *selectedRate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) RequestCar *car;
@property (nonatomic, retain) RequestExterior *exterior;
@property (nonatomic, retain) RequestBundling *bundling;
@property (nonatomic, retain) RequestInterior *interior;
@property (nonatomic, retain) RequestNewCar *theNewCar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) RequestTestdrive *testDrive;
@property (nonatomic, retain) RequestFinalRate *finalRate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Users *owner;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *viewedToRate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *hiddenToRate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *photos;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *diagnosticPhotos;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *rates;
```

## Rates properties

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * cost;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * costOfSale;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * securityComment;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * dateChanged;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * ident;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * identManager;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * identRater;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * identRequest;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Requests *request;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Users *rater;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ViewedToRateRequests *viewed;
@property (nonatomic, retain) HiddenToRateRequests *hidden;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Requests *selectedInRequest;
```

## Trying to fetch

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetch setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Requests" inManagedObjectContext:moc]];
[fetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"!(ANY rates.identRater == %@)", @"someIdent"]];
[fetch setSortDescriptors:@[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dateChanged" ascending:YES]]];
```

If I use any of predicate listed above, CoreData return 0 rows.. but I want to see 1 row..

Please, help me..

Comment: Could you be more specific about what is the criteria the results needs to meet? I see you have an entity named "Requests" which has a one-to-many relationship with Rates. Now, what is the criteria "Requests" needs to meet in order to be fetched on your fetch request?

Comment: so, you are trying to fetch all members of the "Rates" entity in which the selectedInRequest property is not equal to a given value?

Comment: I trying to get all Requests where rates.identRater!='someRaterIdent'

Comment: @MihaelIsaev - you mean where none of the rates have an identRater==@"whatever", right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(rates, $r, $r.identRater == %@).@count == 0", identRater]
```

It would appear that other options are not working correctly so a subquery is the only solution: [Core Data NSPredicate with to-Many Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722930/core-data-nspredicate-with-to-many-relationship)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!  Sorry for this misleading comment earlier, I thought the other answer solved the problem but my test case was poorly written.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track.  It's the string comparison operator that needs adjustment.  And I think your idea number 2 is the most direct way to state your intent.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NONE rates.identRater LIKE %@", identRater];
```

(I haven't tested this).

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't helped.. I was try with CONTAINS[cd] too, but no luck...

Comment: I have tested the above solution and it does work.  Are you certain the data contains such cases?