# how to form predicate to get objects from Core Data that contain string elements from Array

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I need to create a predicate to get object from core data, 
My entity "Form" looks like that:

```
@interface EEForm (CoreDataProperties)
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSDate *date;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *descriptor;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *location;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSMutableSet<Participants *> *participants;
```

entity "Participants" look like that:

```
@interface Participants (CoreDataProperties)

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger indexRow;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *participant;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) EEForm *form;
```

I want to get objects on the base of participants field, that contains all objects from a given array (this array consist of string objects and it changes dependently of what the user selects). 
Fetch request is performed by FetchResultController. I set the predicate in initialisation of it.

I did it in that way, but it includes all objects that contains at least one object from the given array.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchResultController {
    if(_fetchResultController != nil) {
        return _fetchResultController;
    }

    NSPredicate *lPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY participants.participant IN %@", _selectedForPredicatel];
    NSFetchRequest *lRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [lRequest setPredicate:lPredicate];
    NSEntityDescription *lEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Form" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [lRequest setEntity:lEntity];
    [lRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [lRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchResultController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:lRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    fetchResultController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchResultController = fetchResultController;
    NSError *error = nil;
    if(![[self fetchResultController] performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    return fetchResultController;
}
```

Could you please advice how to set predicate properly to filter objects that contain all elements from the given array.

EDIT:
array that is used for predicate looks like that:

```
   _selectedForPredicatel = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Child",@"Adult", @"Group of people", @"Family", @"Teenager", nil];
```

every time user selects parameters by which filter 'Form' objects, this array is updating, so I need fetch request to be done according to it. So if 'Form' has included participants: @"Child",@"Adult",  but in an array _selectedForPredicatel there are objects: @"Adult", @"Group of people", in this case this 'Form' shouldn't be fetched. Should be fetched only that 'Form'that includes both elements of _selectedForPredicatel array.
Thanks a lot for any advice.

Comment: Can there be more than one `Participant` with the same value for the `participant` attribute?

Comment: @pbasdf Yes, there could be a lot of participants with the same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to include the forms if, for each of the user's selections, there is at least one `Participant` that has a `participant` attribute that matches.

If the participant names were unique (at least for each `Form`), you could count the matches and compare to the count of the user's selections.  But if not, you need to create a predicate test each of the user's selections separately, and then combine the results into one big predicate:

```
NSPredicate *template = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(participants, $p, $p.participant == $SELECTED).@count > 0)"];
NSMutableArray *predicateArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *testString in _selectedForPredicatel) {
    NSDictionary *subsVars = @{@"SELECTED" : testString};
    NSPredicate *testPredicate = [template predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:subsVars];
    [predicateArray addObject:testPredicate];
}
NSPredicate *finalPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateArray];
NSLog(@"finalPredicate is %@", finalPredicate);
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"ListEntity"];
fetch.predicate = finalPredicate;
```

Here `template` is a dummy predicate using `$SELECTED` as a placeholder for the user's selection.  The for loop uses this to create a predicate for each of the user's selections and adds it to a mutable array.  The final predicate is built by compounding the array of predicates using `AND` clauses.

It's pretty messy (the final predicate is bad enough, the underlying SQL is horrible) so performance might be dismal.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ANY you can use ALL :

```
 NSPredicate *lPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ALL participants.participant IN %@", _sortByParticipants];
```

This will check if all objects are in your collection.

Comment: thank you very much for answer, but unfortunately it throws an exeption: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported predicate ALL participants.participant IN '