# How to create a fetch request predicate in swift which does not include items with a given attribute from the related entity

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, core-data

I have two entities which are related to each other. The first one is the Transaction entity which has a many-to-many relationship with the other entity named Tag. So a Transaction can have multiple tags and a Tag can have multiple transactions.

I have a method that fetches data from Core Data that can return results that are tagged with a given tag. The predicate I used is as shown below:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(%@ <= date) AND (date < %@) AND (ANY tags IN %@)", argumentArray: [startDate, endDate, tags])
```

It works perfectly. Now what I want to do is to create another fetch request that has a predicate that filter results the other way. Which is to return results that DOES NOT have the given tag.

So I tried the code below:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(%@ <= date) AND (date < %@) AND (tType == %@) AND (NOT ANY tags IN %@)", argumentArray: [startDate, endDate, type.rawValue, tags])
```

and

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(%@ <= date) AND (date < %@) AND (tType == %@) AND (NOT tags IN %@)", argumentArray: [startDate, endDate, type.rawValue, tags])
```

But neither seems to work. All it does is return all items whether they were tagged or not.

Am I missing something here?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This may answer your question: [Core Data NSPredicate with to-Many Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15722930/1187415).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards the right direction @MartinR! I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
let format = "(%@ <= date) AND (date < %@) AND (tType == %@) AND (NOT (tags IN %@))"
let args = [startDate as NSDate, endDate as NSDate, type.rawValue, tags]
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: format, argumentArray: args)
```

Hopefully it should work!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Got an error "unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : "

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of those who encounter the same issue, thanks to @MartinR for pointing me to the right direction. Here's the Predicate I came up with that worked.

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(%@ <= date) AND (date < %@) AND (tType == %@) AND (SUBQUERY(tags, $t, $t IN %@).@count == 0)", argumentArray: [startDate, endDate, type.rawValue, exemptTag])
```

So the key ingredient is the SUBQUERY(tags, $t, $t IN %@).@count == 0 which just essentially searches for the values in exemptTag in the tags property of the item being queried.